# How do I determine the space used within a SQL Server CE database?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Does anyone know how to determine the amount of space used within a SQL Server CE database using C#? I'm writing a routine within a Windows Service that will monitor our SQL Server CE database and attempt to purge data as it approaches its max limit. Right now, I can look directly at the file on disk as a means to discover database size but that seems a little bit like a hack.

I did run across this article which suggests that the best (only?) way is to estimate table size: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827968  Is that correct?

Does anyone have thoughts or suggestions? Is it truly a hack to just look at the size of the file on disk? Does that file size directly correlate to the 4GB data limit?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Not a hack to look at disk, but maybe you should consider another database solution, where you do not have to worry so much about disk Space used, like SQL Server.

Comment: Actually, I would love to move to another database but unfortunately that's just not in the cards at the moment.  I appreciate the insight. Looking at the disk felt a little too easy which is why I asked if anyone else felt it was a hack.  You know how these things go, sometimes the best solution feels almost too easy!